# Can I upload an APK+OBB signed with upload key to Google Play when the signing key is generated by Google?

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-signing

I have accidentally selected "Let google manage app signing key" when I try to upload my first AAB internal track. Now my app's app signing key is generated and stored by Google, I don't have access to it. I only have access to the upload key. **I can't build and upload AAB to Google Play because the size of the build exceeds 150MB**. My question is: can I upload an APK+OBB file to Google Play for release? If the APK was signed by my keystore, which is my upload key, will it be resigned by Google's auto-generated keystore? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can upload a signed apk or AAB  with your local generated keyStore .

1. if you had already selected app signing by google , the signing will be changed to the key generated by the store.
2. if you didn't select this option your signature will remain , and make sure to keep your keystore safe for further updates as its necessary and can't be changed again.